# How to monitor backbone link for bandwidth problems?

Tags: networking, routing, internet, network-speed

Is it possible to monitor the performance of specific internet backbone links, without special access? Or are there any maps or reports publicly available to show the current health of such links?

I have a situation where I believe that there was reduced network speed between my servers in a datacenter in Toronto, and some fraction of their users. It performed consistently well for requests from many parts of the world, but some specific locations were seeing consistently lower speeds. These locations previous had better speeds.

These findings are based on both developers in multiple locations, and monitoring tools such as Pingdom performing checks from around the world. If this was localized to a single city or ISP we would recognize it as such. But this issue affected requests from Europe, east US, and parts of Canada.

So I suspect that some inter-connection had degraded performance. Is there some way to detect or monitor this?

Comment: I would rather suspect issues with peering, not a particular *link*. And you can use looking glasses to see routing tables.

Comment: most devices are enabled for SNMP, did you tried it? Moreover somewhere must be a firewall and this link, why did you not looking there?

Comment: I know a little about BGP and SNMP, but not enough to effectively troubleshoot the issue. I was hoping to find an easy-to-use tool that would identify slow parts of the network, similar to how traceroute can from a single source IP, but from multiple source IPs.